# Creating a window using window.h and no additional libraries

Tags: c++, winapi, window

so I followd Microsofts instructions on how to make a desktop application using C++ and windows.h. I want to make it a specific height/width but when I plug in ints for the numbers, the window doesn't even open anymore.
Here is the code;

```
#pragma once
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>

#define windowWidth = 100;
#define windowHeight = 100;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Hello World",                 // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, // <<=== HERE

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );
```

This is not the full code, you can find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program)

Would really appreciate if you could help me!

Comment: `#define windowWidth = 100;` don't use defines. Remember a #define will do a text replacement.

Comment: whoops, that shouldn't even be in there sorry @drescherjm

Comment: My advice for your question is to show the actual changes that you made.

Comment: I didn't make any changes to the code, I just tried pluging in numbers for "CW_USEDEFAULT", for example 1920, 1080 @drescherjm

Comment: Putting valid numbers in for `CW_USEDEFAULT` should have worked. You may want to try replacing just the first 2 and leaving the other 2 alone.

Comment: That's why I'm confused, when I do so, the window "opens", but its "not there". I can see the application in the taskbar but nothing happens when I tab into it @drescherjm

Comment: Please show the non-working code __not__ the working code.  We may make different edits than you and waste everyone's time.

Comment: The not working code is essentially the same, I just replaced the first two "CW_USEDEFAULT" with 1920 and 1080. Everything else is like in the post above @RichardCritten

Comment: The 1st 2 are the `x` and `y` position - do you have a large monitor ? On my 1080p the window would be off the edge.

Comment: I have a 4k monitor, that shouldn't be the problem @RichardCritten

Comment: Wow, interestingly enough it wouldn't work with CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1920, 1080, but 0,0,1920,1080 does the job. Sorry for the inconvenience